# creating a random multidimension array using rand() with nddata = fix(8*randn(10,5,3))

Tags: matlab

I am currently trying to learn MATLAB independently and had a question about a command that used randn().

```
nddata =  fix(8*randn(10,5,3))
```

I understand what the fix() function does, and the multi dimension array that is created by randn. However, I am not sure what 8 is doing here, it is not multiplying the outcome of the random numbers and it is not part of the limit. So I just want to know the purpose of the 8 here.
Thanks

Comment: Generally on SO; it helps to state what you've tried to help yourself. 

Specifically, for example here, I've tried splitting the expression into two. 
putting the output of `randn` in `temp`
then comparing `temp`to fix(8*temp)

{a cynic, or an epistemologist may ask how you know that it is not, multiplying the outcome}

Comment: _I am not sure what 8 is doing here, it is not multiplying the outcome of the random numbers_ Yes, it is. That's what it's doing

Answer (score 0):

`randn` generated a standard normally distributed matrix of random numbers (standard in this context is defined as mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1). The 8 factor simply stretches this distribution along the x-axis; a scalar multiplication for each value in the 3D matrix. The `fix` function then rounds each value to the nearest integer towards 0, i.e. -3.9 becomes -3.0. This will discretise the data and reduces the standard deviation.

To see this for yourself, split the expression up and create temporary variables for each operation, and step through it with the debugger.